# Use Excel Loop (VBA) to update array ranges

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops

End result desired: Use a macro to select a range of cells (D530:O530, then D531:O531, down to 1029) and "convert" the standard function into an array.

Rather than hitting F2 and CSE 500 times, I figured there should be an easy way to have Excel do the lifting.

I recorded a macro for the first couple lines (as an example) and attempted to then repeat that operation 500 more times.

```
Sub ArrayUpdateLoop()
'
' ArrayUpdateLoop Macro
'
    Range("D530:O530").Select
    For i = 1 To 500
    Range("D530:O530").Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Selection.FormulaArray = "=Spreader(Rollouts,R[-503]C:R[-503]C[14])"
   Next
End Sub
```

The above is my proposed/modified code using a loop, which seems to run, but doesn't actually perform the operation.

This is my first time using a loop to redo an operation X number of times, and I've not found much of the MS documentation/etc. terribly helpful.

Appreciate any feedback or help :-)

Comment: `Dim i&, rng As Range: Set rng = Range("D529:O529"): For i = 1 to To 500: Set rng = rng.Offset(1): rng.FormulaArray = ...: Next`

Comment: try removing the second Range("D530:O530").Select line

Comment: Can't believe I spent so much time on this yesterday afternoon. JohnyL - THANK YOU for a super quick fix. Saved my department (army of one... me!) dozens of hours for updating this every quarter.

Comment: You're welcome! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to offset by one row down in each loop:

```
Sub OffsetDown()
    Dim i&, rng As Range
    '// Start from the row above to line up with loop
    Set rng = Range("D529:O529")
    For i = 1 to To 500
        Set rng = rng.Offset(1) '//Move one cell down
        rng.FormulaArray = ...
    Next
End Sub
```